# CSV not importing JSON with correct format into database

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Just like the title says, here is my code:

```
require 'json'
def import_csv
  path = Rails.root.join('folder1', 'folder2', 'file.csv')
  counter = 0
  puts "inserts on table started..."
  CSV.foreach(path, headers: true) do |row|
    next if row.to_hash['deleted_at'] != nil
    counter += 1
    puts row.to_json #shows correct format
    someModel = someModel.new(row.to_hash) #imports incorrect format of json with backslash in db
    #someModel = someModel.new(row.to_json) #ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
    someModel.skip_callbacks = true
    someModel.save!
    end
  puts "#{counter} inserts on table apps complete"
end
import_csv
```

I can not import the CSV File in the correct format. The import works, but the structure is wrong.

### EXPECTED

```
{"data":{"someData":72}}
```

### GETTING

```
"{\"data\":{\"someData\":72}}"
```

How can I import it with the correct JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

If all headers are correct as of the column names of the model
Maybe you can try:

```rb
JSON.parse(row.to_json)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i still get the error "#ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument." @kevinluo201